# Forward and backward the video while reading by inputstream in java

Tags: java, video, inputstream

Firstly, we have a video in localstorage (say Drive D), and We are reading the video by converting into the bytes and passing it to inputstreamreader and working fine. Our doubt is that, how can we allow user to forward and backward the video while playing , since we are passing the bytes in a sequential manner, how it can be achieved to forward or backward the video while streaming. Please suggest us in a right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously, you can only play what is in memory. If it’s not In memory, you must reload it from the file by seeking. If you can not seek within the file, and it’s not in memory, user seeking is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for reply, will you please elaborate the answer briefly . how to seek to the point where user points(forwards) while playing the video

Comment: Depends on the container and the player and the media the files is stored on. There are dozens (or hundreds) of possible combinations, each with a different answer.

Comment: thanks for reply, and will you provide us the any sample work/example